# Abnormally high Load average on Tomcat despite low traffic

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, tomcat, concurrency

So we have been facing a problem from the past 2 weeks. We have an app that is run on 3 nodes .
The environment is :

```
Framework : Spring Boot on Tomcat
Runtime   : JVM 1.8
OS        : centOS 7
```

The past couple of weeks, the load average of all nodes start from **0 and gradually increase up to 30 within a few hours**. This,despite the fact that we get only about 1-2 requests per second.Also , Tomcat is deployed on a 8GB ,4 core processor and the CPU utilisation  fluctuates **between 380-395%.**

We profiled our application and performed a thread dump. During our analysis, we found that when the **load average > 10**  , the number of **runnable threads stays around 20** , and the **waiting thread count is around 80 .**

The stack trace for these waiting threads are :

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2) native
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175) 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039) 
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(:-1) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(:-1) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
java.lang.Thread.run(:-1)
```

Should also point out that we make heavy use of Springs @Async annotation.We have an Executor with a thread pool of 30 threads.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information. I have installed and profiled with JProfiler but still no success!

Thank you.

Comment: 20 running threads is much bigger than the 4 cores you have. It's 5 threads per core which are doing something really intense judging by the CPU utilisation. What are the stack traces for your running threads? What kind of work they are doing, any heavy calculations, loops etc.? Amount of context switches would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with Tomcat 8 (with JasigCAS service installed) on Debian 8. After start tomcat 8, after few hours, randomly, some cores goes to 100% usage. But tomcat is being responsive. In official tomcat 8 tracker present bug report 60578 (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60578) with similar problem.

As **solution** proposed install new tomcat 8 version (8.5.9) from Debian backports repository. I used this solution and from first look I see that problem solved for me.

Maybe you can install this version to your CentOS 7 and this solve problem for your too?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

The actual issue had nothing to do with Tomcat really. Our code was stuck on a `while` loop that was evaluating to true and running forever. This caused our Tomcat thread pool to hang, and therefore the high load average.